# Как правильно отследить начало следующего дня?

Tags: java, android, calendar

Выдает время по моему часовому поясу.

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

Получаю время в миллисекундах и записываю его (в файл).

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
```

В определенный момент хочу проверить, настал ли следующий день. У меня есть записанное старое значение миллисекунд. Делю его на 86400000 без остатка, чтобы получить количество дней, прошедшее с 1970 года. Затем, получаю актуальное время новым экземпляром Calendar и тоже его делю.

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()/86400000
```

Теперь, если второе число больше - наступил новый день.

Проблема: почему-то второе число дней не подстроено под мой часовой пояс. Хотя вообще, если вывести на экран

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
```

То показывает +4 часа, как и должно быть. Не понимаю, почему так.

Comment: У класса `Calendar` есть методы сравнения даты  `after()` и `before()`

Comment: Покажите полностью весь ваш код, постараюсь помочь

Comment: Как насчет ``Calendar.getInstance().get(DAY_OF_MONTH);``? Сразу возвращает число месяца и не надо ничего высчитывать.

Comment: @pavlofff  Я так понимаю, они работают с моментами времени, а не с днями?

Comment: @Эникейщик А если прошел ровно месяц и будет такое же число?

Comment: У вас в условии только про следующий день. Если нужно сравнивать месяц, то берите и месяц тоже.

Comment: Можно брать ``Calendar.getInstance().get(DAY_OF_YEAR);``  и получать порядковый номер дня в году. Тогда проблема с "прошел ровно месяц" будет решена. Но, конечно, остается проблема "прошел ровно год" :)

Comment: @Эникейщик Да-да, вот только что закончил тестить - все работает, спасибо) Да год, фиг с ним. Проверить тоже можно, но в моей задаче не нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример вашего кода, и его недочёта, как я понял. Почему у вас получается разные пояса непонятно. В коде ниже всё хорошо относительно этого.

```
   //OLD Time
   String date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString(); // Выдает дату на телефоне
   Log.d("myDate","oldDate: "+date);
   Long oldTimeInMsec =  Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
   Log.d("myDateInMsec","myOldDateInMsec: "+oldTimeInMsec.toString());

   final Long oldTimeInMsecDiv = oldTimeInMsec/86400000; // Одно число


    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //new time
            String newDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString(); // Выдает дату на телефоне
            Log.d("myDate","newDate: " + newDate);
            Long newTimeInMsec =  Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
            Log.d("myDateInMsec", "mynewDateInMsec: "+newTimeInMsec.toString());

            Long newTimeInMsecDiv = newTimeInMsec/86400000;     //Точно такое же число т.к спустя 2 секунды изменения во времени очень
                                                                // маленькие и не влияют на результат в целом числе( при делении)

            if(newTimeInMsecDiv>oldTimeInMsecDiv){
                Log.d("myDate: ","Наступил новый день");
            }else{
                Log.d("myDate: "," не Наступил новый день");
            }
        }
    }, 2000);
```

Код для получения разницы во времени:

```
 final Date startDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final Date endDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            Calendar diff = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
            diff.setTimeInMillis(endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime());
            Log.d("Date", "Work Time: " + getCoolTime(diff));
        }
    }, 2000);

}
public String getCoolTime(Calendar time) {
    return (time.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - 1) + "d "
            + time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
            + time.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + time.get(Calendar.SECOND);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за подробный ответ, буду разбираться.

Comment: @keltkelt если ответ вам помог, ответьте его как лучший.